# Define a sequence of integers $H(n)$ by $H(0) = 1$, $H(1) = 3$ and $H(n+1) = H(n) + H(n-1)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Then show that $H(n)$ can be expressed in the form $a\cdot(\psi(1))^n + b\cdot(\psi(2))^n$ and that $\psi(1)$ and $\psi(2)$ are the same numbers that occur in the proof of the Fibonacci numbers.

I'm quite lost with this question.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the (usual) Fibonacci recurrence?

Comment: set $H(n)=q^n$ and compute $q$

Comment: Hint: Compute $a,b$ from 
$$H(0) = 1 = a\cdot(\psi(1))^0 + b\cdot(\psi(2))^0$$
$$H(1) = 3 = a\cdot(\psi(1))^1 + b\cdot(\psi(2))^1$$
then use induction to prove the formula for $H(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Write the following (this is a useful *general* method to solve linear recurrence relations, likely not to be the most concise in this particular case):
$$
\begin{align*}
H_{n} &= H_n \\
H_{n+1} &= H_{n}+H_{n-1}
\end{align*}
$$
or, in matrix form for $X_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=} \begin{pmatrix} H_n \\ H_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}$,
$$
\begin{align*}
X_n = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} X_{n-1}
\end{align*}
$$
with $X_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$. Writing $A\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, observe that $X_n = A^n X_0$. If you were to diagonalize $A$ to have it of the form
$$
A = P\begin{pmatrix} \psi_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \psi_2\end{pmatrix} P^{-1}
$$, by canceling out the products $P^{-1}P$ you would get 
$$X_n = P\begin{pmatrix} \psi_1^n & 0 \\ 0 & \psi_2^n\end{pmatrix} P^{-1} X_0$$
which you can then explicitly compute to obtain your result.

Answer (score 0):

we have $q^{n+1}=q^n+q^{n-1}$
dividing by $q^n$ we get
$q=1+q^{-1}$
and we get
$q^2-q-1=0$
now solve this equation for $q$